# Show that every polytope is bounded

Tags: convex-optimization

The definition of polytope is the convex hull of a finite set. Thus:
$$
\parallel\sum_j\lambda _j x_j\parallel\le\sum_j\lambda_j\parallel x_j\parallel\le\sum_j\lambda_j\max_j \parallel x_j\parallel=M\sum_j\lambda_j=M
$$
where $M=\max_j \parallel x_j\parallel$

And how can I conclude from above that every polytope is bounded?

Comment: What is $x^*$ here? Since $0\le\lambda_i\le1$, you might also simply bound by $\left\|\sum_j\lambda_jx_j\right\|\le \sum_j|\lambda_j|\,\|x_j\|\le \sum_j |\lambda_j|M=M\sum_j \lambda_j=M$ where $M=\max\{\,\|x_j\|\colon 1\le j\le n\,\}$.

Comment: I was using x* to indicate maximum value of x but now I modified it to $\max_j x_j$ hope this is clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct.  And it seems to me that you proved your assertion.  You assumed $M = \max_{1 \le i \le m} \|x_i\|$, of course.

Comment: Is it because the maximum of x lies inside convex hull and hence it is bounded (by the maximum value) ?

Comment: Not really.  It is because the maximum of a finite number of real numbers is itself a real number, and hence bounded.

Comment: And where you had the superscript *, that part makes no sense.  Just leave it out of the chain of inequalities.